# How can I create a spotlight with image texture using eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image]I´m making this question because I´ve been on a project and I´ve just been able to create a spotlight with image texture using cycles, but I´ve been using Eevee with all the project and I need to use the same render engine with everything I create, so has someone been able to create a spotlight with image texture using Eevee?

Now you can see the spotlight I´m using and the nodes I´m using

Comment: could you please give more details about your image texture in Cycles?

Comment: If you mean you want an image to cast off light as an emission, this only really works in Cycles. To make it work in EEVEE, you will need _Screen Space Reflections_ (if you want to see the image in reflections), and an _Irradiance Volume_ to make the glowing light "cast" on to things.  However, keep in mind that this is type of effect is rather limited by the eevee renderer, and requires much tweaking to make it look accurate - it will never look as "real" as cycles, and may not even be capable of producing the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Another way of looking at it (if that's all your after) is that there is a difference between how "lights" are used in EEVEE and Cycles. EEVEE differentiates between "lights" (point lights, spot, etc..) and emissive objects, whereas in Cycles, _all_ lights are emissive objects (if you select a light in Cycles, go to its properties, check "use nodes" and go to the shading tab, you will see that the light is made of an Emission shader)

Comment: Now you can take a look at the image I uploaded, I hope it can help a bit

Comment: If you want to take a look at the Blend file here it is:   https://pasteall.org/media/a/d/adc821de0f66b4a8f73d94294ba3e88d.blend

Comment: you're probably of best if you use a project UV modifier

Comment: Ok, I´m going to try it, I hope it works, thanks

Comment: Hello, I tried the UV project and it kind of worked, because what if I want the "Spider signal" to project over a character?   I´ll need to change the image texture the character has to the Spider signal image, also you can´t project the image without taking out the image texture the object already has, like for example, if I have a city, and I want the Spider Signal to project on the walls, I´ll need to change the window or brick texture the walls have, so the UV project modifier is useful at some points, but I think it is not what I´m looking for, thanks

Comment: If you need the logo only on a wall or a character but not on two objects (partly) at the same time then you can mix the logo in the material with a second UV map and use the UV project modifier. If needed you also can add a "switch" to the *Fac* input to turn it on & off: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bey5I.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your help, that really worked!